# Installing .apk

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-install-apk

I generated an apk file for Android version 2.2 with Eclipse => "export", then I dropped it in my Galaxy ACE GT-S5830M (Android 2.3.6) and tried to install, but I got this message: "The application you are installing will replace another application." But I was installing this app for the first time. When I clicked OK, the installation started but stopped in two seconds and I got this error: "Application not installed".
I tried several times. I also tried on my friend's smartphone, he has a Google Nexus and it installed successfully. Also I checked "Allow installation of non-Market applications" but it didn't help.

Does anyone have any ideas what can I do ?

Comment: probably problem with your package name. What is the current value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your application is using a "likely to be unique" package name, and not something like `com.example` which may be used by other projects you've ran on your phone. See [Package naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions) for examples, which usually revolves around some domain name you own to lessen the likelihood of conflicts.

Comment: Yeah that's right I had two my app with same package name, I deleted old one and everything installed successful.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, happened to me when I installed a finalized app I wrote after testing the debug version for a while. The 2 apps are considered the same, but have different signatures, so the install fail. I removed the old debug version, and the install worked.

Comment: also happens when you try to debug the same project from different workstations.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to rename the application name AND package names in eclipse because that's the way android identifies equal applications